# Getting all characters after the last '-' in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working within some very strict pack-end limitations and have a client that is unrelenting in his request so I'm forced to do something in .js that I'd rather not do.

Anyway, here goes.

I have client reviews. At the end of those reviews I have '- United States' or '- Australia'. Basically, at the end of every review I have '- [location]'. I need to pull that string out of the review text and then insert it into a span. I'm using jQuery, so I'd like to stick with that.

I've sorted out how to run through each review and insert it where I need it, but I have not figured out how to get that string of text from each review and then remove it from each review. That's where I could really use some help.

Example text:

```
<div class="v2_review-content">
    <h4>These earplugs are unbelievable!</h4>
    <p class="v2_review-text">These are the only earplugs I have ever used that completely block out annoying sounds. I use them at night due to the fact I am an extremely light sleeper and the slightest noise will wake me up. These actually stick to the ear in an airtight suction and do not come out at all until I pull them off in the morning. These are as close to the perfect earplug as you can get! - United States</p>
    <p class="v2_review-author">Jimmy, March 06, 2013</p>
</div>
```

I also have underscore.js available if that helps.

Comment: find every occurrence of `" - "` in your string, get the last one, all text after that is your country. remove it from the string and place it in a new element, append to paragraph tag..

Comment: So, what have you already tried? Are you stuck on extracting the string from that HTML? Or on parsing out the location? On changing the existing DOM?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't that work? What happens instead? Help us help you.

Comment: Split on ' - ' and the last element of the array is the country

Comment: I've searched to find the function/syntax I should use but I'm stuck as this is an area of .js I've never touched before so I'm not even sure how to go about doing it. JavaScript being a client-side language and string parsing being resource intensive, I wanted to ask the pros what the best way of doing it was.

Comment: Unless you're looking at an enormous (>1k at the very least) number of reviews, you won't have to worry about the system being taxed by your query. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No need for jQuery for the actual string manipulation - a little clunky, but easy to understand:

```
text = 'Something -that - has- dashes - World';
parts = text.split('-');
loc = parts.pop();
new_text = parts.join('-');
```

So,

```
loc == ' World';
new_text == 'Something -that - has- dashes ';
```

Whitespace can be trimmed or ignored (as it often doesn't matter inside HTML).

Answer (score 17):

First split the stirng on '-' which will give you an array of strings between the dashes.  Then use it as a stack and pop the last element off and call trim to remove any of that pesky whitespace (unless you like your whitespace of course).

```
"String - Location".split('-').pop().trim(); // "Location"
```

So using jQuery it would be

```
$('.v2_review-text').html().split('-').pop().trim(); // "United States"
```

Or using vanilla JS

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('v2_review-text')[0].innerHTML;
text.split('-').pop().trim(); // "United States"
```

Comment: Nice answer. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyZxh/) that implements your answer. (I wanted to see it work, and it works great). Feel free to modify/include in your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this

```
str2 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably to use jQuery to get the element, and native JavaScript to get the string:

```
var fullReview = $('.v2_review-text').text(); //assumes only one review exists, adjust for your use.
var country = fullReview.substring(fullReview.lastIndexOf(' - ') + 1); //TODO correct for -1 if ' - ' not found.
```

This is just a proof of concept; the rest should be relatively easy to figure out. Some things to look up while you're learning: [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Surely doesn't look like native JS...

Comment: That will retrieve any text after the first dash, OP asked for the last one afaik.

Comment: @Shomz: true, adjusted!

Comment: @ΔάκηςΑνδρέου: Are you sure? lastIndexOf should get the last position of the dash.

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $('.v2_review-text').text();
var city_array = val.split('-');
var city = city_array[city_array.length - 1];
```

Hopefully i have helped you buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
var completeText = $('.v2_review-text')[0].value;
var country = completeText.substr(completeText.lastIndexOf('-'), completeText.lenght - 1);
```

Comment: This worked for me,
var completeText = $('.v2_review-text')[0].value;
var country = completeText.substr(completeText.lastIndexOf('-')+ 1, completeText.lenght );