# JavaScript remove everything before a character for a URL array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a blog featuring content within a div.

I have the following script which returns all `a href` tags in a blog.

```
 function (){
 var tags = [];
 var count = $(".blog-featured").children().length;
 for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
 tags.push($('.blog-featured').children().eq(i).find('a').attr('href'));    
 }
return tags;
}
```

This is returning an array of URLs like the following [undefined, www.test.com.au/product/url/60145675?product/computer, www.test.com.au/product/url/6014 8796/test/products]

I would like to manipulate this array to:

1. Remove any spaces which may have occurred (not sure why but the script returns URLs with spaces)
2. Remove anything before a '6' and anything after the the 8(or 9 if the space isn't removed_) character product number
3. Remove any undefined values.

So the final array looks something like [60145675,60148796].

Comment: What do you mean by Remove anything before a '6' and anything after the the 8(or 9 if the space isn't removed_) character product number? 
Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Sorry so the product number I want returned is always 8 characters long, and starts with a 6. (however sometimes there is a space in the number making it 9 characters long). in terms of what i have tried, basically adding all the functions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646389/getting-all-characters-after-the-last-in-a-string to the end of .attr('href')

Answer (score 0):

just split the href and replace any spaces before pushing it into the array:

eg: www.test.com.au/product/url/6014 8796/test/products

```
var loc =location.href;
var locPortions=loc.split("/");//splits the href at each "/";
var num=locPortions[3].replace(/ /g,"");//gets the desired portion of the href and replaces any spaces with no character - removing the spaces;
tags.push(num);//gives 60148796 out of the original href;
```

or to put it into your original function:
EDIT - function below amended to check for "6" at start of the locPortions.

```
     function (){
     var tags = [];
     var count = $(".blog-featured").children().length;
     for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        var loc = $('.blog-featured').children().eq(i).find('a').attr('href'); 
        var locPortions=loc.split("/");
      for (ii=0;ii<locPortions.length;ii++){
       if(locPortions[ii].charAt(0)=="6")
       {
          var num=locPortions[ii].replace(/ /g,"");}
          tags.push(num);
       }
  }
    return tags;
    }
```

Comment: thanks gavgrif the only problem is that my urls are not structured very nicely (e.g. there is not always 3 '/' before the number. and its not always only the number between forward slashes.) as such the only way to find it in the a tag is via searching for the 6

Comment: answer amended to fulfil this - all you have to do is split the href by the method as described, and then iterate through each portion and check whether the first character is a "^" and if so - push that (assuming that the 6 is always present and always the start of the desired number.