# Getting the last substring value of a string with hyphens in it

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I need your help,

How can I get the last value (sub-string) of a text string that has hyphens in it?

```
var instr = "OTHER-REQUEST-ALPHA"
```

...some processing here to get the outstr value

```
var outstr = "ALPHA"
```

Comment: Potential duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646389/getting-all-characters-after-the-last-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) methods.

```js
var instr = "OTHER-REQUEST-ALPHA";

console.log(
  instr.split('-').pop()
)
```

---

Or use [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastindexof) and [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) methods

```js
var instr = "OTHER-REQUEST-ALPHA";

console.log(
  instr.substr(instr.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)
)
```

---

Or using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```js
var instr = "OTHER-REQUEST-ALPHA";

console.log(
  instr.match(/[^-]*$/)[0]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to simply split the string by your delimeter (ie. `-`) and get the last segment:

```
var inString = "OTHER-REQUEST-ALPHA"
var outString = inString.split("-").slice(-1)[0]
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Use SPLIT and POP

```
"String - MONKEY".split('-').pop().trim(); // "MONKEY"
```

Or This

```
string2 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-"))
```